# Alternative TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

This query works well as you can see I have to put split between between @SearchCriteria and the rest of the query due to it's varchar.  If I forced, the syntax works well BUT it return nothing when you query possible because extra '

Can you help?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_rte_GetRateList]
(
    @TenantID        INT,
    @CustomerID      BIGINT = -1,   
    @SearchCriteria  VARCHAR(64) = '', 
    @SortBy          VARCHAR(16) = '',
    @SortType        VARCHAR(16) = '',
    @Debug           BIT = 0
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000),
            @paramlist  nvarchar(4000)  

    IF (@SearchCriteria = '')
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT r.TenantID, r.RateID, r.RateGUID, r.RateCode, r.RateName, r.RateDescription, r.ValidityUTCDate, r.CreatedUTCTimeStamp, 
                            r.CreatedIP, r.CreatedBy, r.LastModifiedUTCTimeStamp, r.LastModifiedIP, r.LastModifiedBy, r.IsActive, 
                            c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, rt.RateTypeID, rt.RateTypeName, s.SupplierID, s.SupplierName, r.FixedLineAmount, r.MobileAmount, r.DataAmount, r.OtherAmount, 
                            (r.FixedLineAmount + r.MobileAmount + r.DataAmount + r.OtherAmount) AS TotalAmount, 
                            r.CreatedUTCTimeSTamp,
                            STUFF((SELECT '', '' + ct.CustomerTypeName 
                                    FROM glb_CustomerTypes ct JOIN glb_CustomerCustomerTypes cct ON cct.CustomerTypeID = ct.CustomerTypeID 
                                    WHERE cct.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
                                    GROUP BY ct.CustomerTypeName FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 2, '''') AS CustomerTypeName 
                        FROM dbo.rte_Rates r 
                                INNER JOIN dbo.rte_RateTypes rt ON r.RateTypeID = rt.RateTypeID 
                                INNER JOIN dbo.glb_Suppliers s ON r.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.glb_Customers c ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
                                INNER JOIN dbo.glb_Addresses a ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.glb_AddressTypes at ON a.AddressTypeID = at.AddressTypeID
                        WHERE   at.AddressTypeCode = ''GLB_ADT_PHYSCLDDRS'' AND
                                r.TenantID = @xTenantID AND 
                                rt.TenantID = @xTenantID AND 
                                s.TenantID = @xTenantID AND 
                                r.IsActive = 1 AND
                                rt.IsActive = 1 AND
                                c.IsActive = 1 AND 
                                c.CustomerID = @xCustomerID '
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT r.TenantID, r.RateID, r.RateGUID, r.RateCode, r.RateName, r.RateDescription, r.ValidityUTCDate, r.CreatedUTCTimeStamp, 
                            r.CreatedIP, r.CreatedBy, r.LastModifiedUTCTimeStamp, r.LastModifiedIP, r.LastModifiedBy, r.IsActive, 
                            c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, rt.RateTypeID, rt.RateTypeName, s.SupplierID, s.SupplierName, r.FixedLineAmount, r.MobileAmount, r.DataAmount, r.OtherAmount, 
                            (r.FixedLineAmount + r.MobileAmount + r.DataAmount + r.OtherAmount) AS TotalAmount, 
                            r.CreatedUTCTimeSTamp,
                            STUFF((SELECT '', '' + ct.CustomerTypeName 
                                    FROM glb_CustomerTypes ct JOIN glb_CustomerCustomerTypes cct ON cct.CustomerTypeID = ct.CustomerTypeID 
                                    WHERE cct.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
                                    GROUP BY ct.CustomerTypeName FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 2, '''') AS CustomerTypeName 
                        FROM dbo.rte_Rates r 
                                INNER JOIN dbo.rte_RateTypes rt ON r.RateTypeID = rt.RateTypeID 
                                INNER JOIN dbo.glb_Suppliers s ON r.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.glb_Customers c ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
                                INNER JOIN dbo.glb_Addresses a ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.glb_AddressTypes at ON a.AddressTypeID = at.AddressTypeID
                        WHERE   at.AddressTypeCode = ''GLB_ADT_PHYSCLDDRS'' AND
                                r.TenantID = @xTenantID AND 
                                rt.TenantID = @xTenantID AND 
                                s.TenantID = @xTenantID AND 
                                r.IsActive = 1 AND
                                rt.IsActive = 1 AND
                                c.IsActive = 1 AND 
                                c.CustomerID = @xCustomerID AND 
                                (r.RateCode LIKE ''%' + @SearchCriteria + '%'' OR
                                 r.RateName LIKE ''%' + @SearchCriteria + '%'' OR
                                 rt.RateTypeName LIKE ''%' + @SearchCriteria + '%'' OR
                                 r.RateDescription LIKE ''%' + @SearchCriteria + '%'' OR
                                 s.SupplierCode LIKE ''%' + @SearchCriteria + '%'' OR
                                 s.SupplierName LIKE ''%' + @SearchCriteria + '%'' OR
                                 c.CustomerCode LIKE ''%' + @SearchCriteria + '%'' OR
                                 c.CustomerName LIKE ''%' + @SearchCriteria + '%'' OR
                                 c.CustomerDescription LIKE ''%' + @SearchCriteria + '%'' ) '                       
    END

    SELECT @sql = @sql + 'ORDER BY ' + @SortBy + ' ' + @SortType

    IF (@Debug = 1) PRINT @sql   

    SELECT @paramlist = '@xTenantID INT, @xCustomerID BIGINT'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist, @TenantID, @CustomerID
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just double any quotes in @SearchCriteria, but that won't protect you against all forms of SQL injection - which you can only do by getting away from dynamic SQL.

I'm not 100% sure you **need** dynamic SQL for this particular problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off initializing the @SearchCriteria to NULL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_rte_GetRateList]
(   ...
    @SearchCriteria      VARCHAR(64), --inits as NULL
    ....
)

    IF @SearchCriteria IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

       SET @SearchCriteria = REPLACE(@SearchCriteria, '''', '''''')
       ...
    END
    ELSE
       ...
```

I get why you setup the dynamic SQL the way you did - I noticed the paramlist doesn't have @SearchCriteria in it, so you don't have to define the param instances of @SearchCriteria.  Might consider full text searches when you have 2+ columns from the same table - likely faster, and less complicated SQL.